# Django queryset filter based on parent of parent

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Say I have the models Teacher, Course, Student. Student model has a foreignKey one-to-many- to Course, and Course has a foreignKey one-to-many to Teacher. When getting a queryset of all Student objects, is there a way to query them based on Teacher?

Comment: is you assign any `related_name` in Teacher field in Course-Model and also `related_name` for course-field in Student Model ?

Comment: what is the status of your post. Do you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say `teacher` is a teacher's uuid/primary key then following look-up should work for you

```
Student.objects.filter(course__teacher=teacher)
```